# Why I am I getting the same value for a field in all of my array objects for useQuery?

Tags: react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I have a useQuery that returns data of the first item inserted. For context, I have an ecommerce website with grocery products, suppose I add an apple with quantiy of 4. Next, when I add another order with quantiy 10, it adds correctly in the database and I get correct results in the apollo playground. But when I am pulling data using the below code in  Apollo client it has all the orders of that user with different order ids but has the quantiy of the first order made for apple.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(queries.GET_USER_ORDERS, {
            fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
            variables: {
                userId: currentUser.uid,
            },
        });
```

Graphql query:

```
const GET_USER_ORDERS = gql`
    query Query($userId: String) {
        userOrders(userId: $userId) {
            _id
            userId
            products {
                _id
                name
                price
                orderedQuantity
            }
            status
            createdAt
            flag
            total
            
        }
    }
 `;
```

So essentially I am seeing all products, but with quantity of 4 for each. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change fetch policy

```
fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
```

also check if you are updating this query result after new order placing mutation (if you are it may cause updating with wrong values )
if you set `fetchPolicy: "no-cache"` you don't have to update query result after mutation